# Combine grep and sed to extract lines of data from a text file

Tags: awk, sed, grep, sh

I must extract data from text files, but the provided files are not well formed. I found a way to get the data lines and place a separator between the values, but there is a small amount of data I’m unable to get.
The one that I miss are the numbers containing dash, like the first one in the next example, 978-2-204-06959-5.

An example of data source file (a sample):

```
    978-2-204-06959-5   Reviens a la vie! (TOME 2)  32,56   0,00    100,00  1
    9782017205722   Parce qu'on ne vous demande pa  6,90    39,54   40,00   2
    9782019464080   Secrets d'alchimistes : appren  3,95    19,77   40,00   1
    9782019464257   Rencontrez votre guide spiritu  10,85   66,51   40,00   3
    9782100841295   Le regard intérieur : méditer   3,95    20,37   40,00   1
    9782213712758   POUR L'AMOUR DU MONDE   39,95   2,97    40,00   1
    9782226450241   Le défi de Jérusalem    149,75  8,85    40,00   5
    9782378803063   Quand la mort éclaire la vie    3,95    23,97   40,00   1
```

Here is the command line I used to get the data and “CSV” it :

```
grep -P “(?<!\d)\d{13}” SourceDataFile.txt | sed -e “s/^[ \t]*//” | sed "s/\t/|/g” > Temp.csv
```

Result file excerpt :

```
9782204069595|Reviens a la vie! (TOME 2)    |32,56|0,00|100,00|1
9782017205722|Parce qu'on ne vous demande pa|6,90|39,54|40,00|2
9782019464080|Secrets d'alchimistes : appren|3,95|19,77|40,00|1
9782019464257|Rencontrez votre guide spiritu|10,85|66,51|40,00|3
...
```

Maybe my piped command is not the way you would have used, I know that with awk it may be simpler. I’m just not very good with awk…

Thanks!

Comment: please update the question to show the (wrong) output and the (correct) expected output, making sure both sets of output correspond with the provided samlpe input

Comment: `grep -P “(?<!\d)(\d{13}|[0-9\-]{17}”` might do the job. If you could share other wrong data that is in this file, we could also whip this up in AWK for you, which I would agree, is a better tool for the job.

Comment: rignt now the 3 lines of output you've provided don't seem to match with any of the input lines you've provided, so it's going to be hard for us to understand what you expect the output to look like

Comment: I just edited to clarify my question. The result just shows the 4 first lines of the file, the rest being the continuity.
It's the "dashed" 978xxxx that I'm not able to get the data line.

Comment: why does the 1st line show .... *a)* `TOME 2` converted to `TOME2` ... *b)* several new trailing spaces for the 2nd column/field ... ?

Answer (score 3):

Assumptions:

- we only want lines where the first column has a total of 13 digits (after discounting all non-digits)

Last line (first column is only 6 digits) added for demonstration purposes:

```
$ cat SourceDataFile.txt
978-2-204-06959-5   Reviens a la vie! (TOME 2)  32,56   0,00    100,00  1
9782017205722   Parce qu'on ne vous demande pa  6,90    39,54   40,00   2
9782019464080   Secrets d'alchimistes : appren  3,95    19,77   40,00   1
9782019464257   Rencontrez votre guide spiritu  10,85   66,51   40,00   3
9782100841295   Le regard intérieur : méditer   3,95    20,37   40,00   1
9782213712758   POUR L'AMOUR DU MONDE   39,95   2,97    40,00   1
9782226450241   Le défi de Jérusalem    149,75  8,85    40,00   5
9782378803063   Quand la mort éclaire la vie    3,95    23,97   40,00   1
978237          Ignore this line of input       3,95    23,97   40,00   1
```

One `GNU awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS = "[ ]{2,}"                      # input field delimiter is 2+ spaces
        OFS = "|" 
      }
      { f1 = $1                             # make copy of first column
        gsub(/[^0-9]/,"",f1)                # remove everything but digits from f1
        if (length(f1) == 13) {             # if f1 is exactly 13 digits long
           $1 = f1                          # replace first column with the 13-digit result
           print                            # print the new line
        }
      }
' SourceDataFile.txt
```

This generates:

```
9782204069595|Reviens a la vie! (TOME 2)|32,56|0,00|100,00|1
9782017205722|Parce qu'on ne vous demande pa|6,90|39,54|40,00|2
9782019464080|Secrets d'alchimistes : appren|3,95|19,77|40,00|1
9782019464257|Rencontrez votre guide spiritu|10,85|66,51|40,00|3
9782100841295|Le regard intérieur : méditer|3,95|20,37|40,00|1
9782213712758|POUR L'AMOUR DU MONDE|39,95|2,97|40,00|1
9782226450241|Le défi de Jérusalem|149,75|8,85|40,00|5
9782378803063|Quand la mort éclaire la vie|3,95|23,97|40,00|1
```

Comment: The solution provided by @JNevill work.

Comment: I did try the awk provided by @markp-fuso, but adapting it for Windows DOS (I know, not good, but it's at work) is tricky.
The quotes seems to bug, even if I use awk -f script.awk

Comment: your `grep/sed/sed` script contains 'smart' quotes which means your code (as is) generates all sorts of errors in my environments (cywgin in Win10; Ubuntu); my answer does not contain smart quotes and thus generates no errors in my envs; not sure I understand how you're running this answer/code in `Windows DOS` ... if you're cut-n-pasting into a Windows/DOS 'cmd' window ... exactly what version of `awk` are you using?

Comment: I use CoreUtils for Windows, but I think I installed awk separately. This is awk 3.1.6.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you have a tab-separated file that you want to be pipe separated.

Given this file (with the actual tabs shown as `<\t>`):

```
  978-2-204-06959-5<\t>Reviens a la vie! (TOME 2)<\t>32,56<\t>0,00<\t>100,00<\t>1
  9782017205722<\t>Parce qu'on ne vous demande pa<\t>6,90<\t>39,54<\t>40,00<\t>2
  9782019464080<\t>Secrets d'alchimistes : appren<\t>3,95<\t>19,77<\t>40,00<\t>1
  9782019464257<\t>Rencontrez votre guide spiritu<\t>10,85<\t>66,51<\t>40,00<\t>3
  9782100841295<\t>Le regard intérieur : méditer<\t>3,95<\t>20,37<\t>40,00<\t>1
  9782213712758<\t>POUR L'AMOUR DU MONDE<\t>39,95<\t>2,97<\t>40,00<\t>1
  9782226450241<\t>Le défi de Jérusalem<\t>149,75<\t>8,85<\t>40,00<\t>5
  9782378803063<\t>Quand la mort éclaire la vie<\t>3,95<\t>23,97<\t>40,00<\t>1
  982378803063<\t>Ignorer cette ligne<\t>1,23<\t>3,97<\t>45,00<\t>3
```

If you want to validate that the value in `$1` field is 13 characters:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"; OFS="|"} 
{gsub(/[^[:digit:]]/,"",$1); $1=$1}
length($1)==13' file.txt
```

After the replacement of the non digits in `$1` the length check filters out all lines where the digits in the first field is not 13 characters.

If the space at the start of each line is a `\t` versus spaces as your example portraits, you can replace that:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"; OFS="|"} 
{sub(/^\t/,""); gsub(/[^[:digit:]]/,"",$1); $1=$1}
length($1)==13' file.txt
```

Either prints:

```
9782204069595|Reviens a la vie! (TOME 2)|32,56|0,00|100,00|1
9782017205722|Parce qu'on ne vous demande pa|6,90|39,54|40,00|2
9782019464080|Secrets d'alchimistes : appren|3,95|19,77|40,00|1
9782019464257|Rencontrez votre guide spiritu|10,85|66,51|40,00|3
9782100841295|Le regard intérieur : méditer|3,95|20,37|40,00|1
9782213712758|POUR L'AMOUR DU MONDE|39,95|2,97|40,00|1
9782226450241|Le défi de Jérusalem|149,75|8,85|40,00|5
9782378803063|Quand la mort éclaire la vie|3,95|23,97|40,00|1
```

---

If the length of `$1` does not matter, here is a simpler awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"; OFS="|"} 
gsub(/[^[:digit:]]/,"",$1)' file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks to all who provided help here !

I managed to do what I want with combination of sed and awk, using awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"; OFS="|"} 
{gsub(/[^[:digit:]]/,"",$1); $1=$1}
length($1)==13' file.txt

I used sed before this, to remove lines of info before the data and the leading spaces and tabs before the first column.

Comment: You actually do not need to use sed for the leading spaces before `$1`. The `gsub(/[^[:digit:]]/,"",$1)` removes the spaces but not any leading tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding

```
grep -P “(?<!\d)\d{13}” SourceDataFile.txt | sed -e “s/^[ \t]*//” | sed "s/\t/|/g” > Temp.csv
```

you do not need to use `sed` twice, as you might give more than 1 instruction for `sed` using `-e` multiple times, consider following simple example, let `file.txt` content be

```
  123;456
  789;101
```

then

```
sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' -e 's/;/|/g' file.txt
```

gives output

```
123|456
789|101
```

You might also use `-n` combined with `p`rint command to filter lines, say if I want to get from above lines starting with `1` (after substitutions) I could do that by

```
sed -n -e 's/^[ \t]*//' -e 's/;/|/g' -e '/^1/p' file.txt
```

which would give

```
123|456
```

As you have used negative lookbehind in your `grep` it is impossible to use it as-is in `sed` which does not support that, however if you are able to find regular expression using just `sed` features, your command might be converted into single `sed`.

*(tested in GNU sed 4.8)*

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{gsub(/  +/,"|"); gsub(/-/,"",$2); sub(/^\|/,"")}1' inputfile

9782204069595|Reviens-a la vie! (TOME 2)|32,56|0,00|100,00|1
9782017205722|Parce qu'on ne vous demande pa|6,90|39,54|40,00|2
9782019464080|Secrets d'alchimistes : appren|3,95|19,77|40,00|1
9782019464257|Rencontrez votre guide spiritu|10,85|66,51|40,00|3
9782100841295|Le regard intérieur : méditer|3,95|20,37|40,00|1
9782213712758|POUR L'AMOUR DU MONDE|39,95|2,97|40,00|1
9782226450241|Le défi de Jérusalem|149,75|8,85|40,00|5
9782378803063|Quand la mort éclaire la vie|3,95|23,97|40,00|1


$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{gsub(/  +/,"|"); NF=NF-1; gsub(/-/,"",$NF)}1' <(rev inputfile)|rev

9782204069595|Reviens-a la vie! (TOME 2)|32,56|0,00|100,00|1
9782017205722|Parce qu'on ne vous demande pa|6,90|39,54|40,00|2
9782019464080|Secrets d'alchimistes : appren|3,95|19,77|40,00|1
9782019464257|Rencontrez votre guide spiritu|10,85|66,51|40,00|3
9782100841295|Le regard intérieur : méditer|3,95|20,37|40,00|1
9782213712758|POUR L'AMOUR DU MONDE|39,95|2,97|40,00|1
9782226450241|Le défi de Jérusalem|149,75|8,85|40,00|5
9782378803063|Quand la mort éclaire la vie|3,95|23,97|40,00|1
```